# ¿Como creo mi propio error en Python™?

Tags: python

Mi necesidad es crear mi propio error
algo así:

```
raise ErrorSistema_Problema("Error")
```

¿Como creo esto sin que me diga

> ErrorSistema_Problema is not defined

?

Answer (score -1):

Es muy facil, solo hay que definir la clase "ErrorSistema_Problema" y darle el argumento "_StandardError"

```
#Definimos "_StandardError"
_StandardError=Exception 
# Si esto no funciona, revisa el archivo
# llamado builtins.pyi
# En este archivo se definen las cosas mas importantes, como
# la funcion print()
```

```
#Creamos la clase del error
class ErrorSistema_Problema(_StandardError) : ...
```

¡ Y listo !
¡Ya podremos usar el raise con nuestro error!

(

```
raise ErrorSistema_Problema("Error Del Sistema")
```

)

¡Sin Errores de por medio, solo el que creamos jaja!

Comment: La forma correcta es creando `class MiPropioError(Exception)`.

Comment: No es lo mismo? yo lo probe y funciono bien, aparte, `_StandardError` es igual a `Exception`, es lo mismo

Comment: Es innecesario, confuso.